# Socket IO: auth with jwt with payload

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, jwt

I'm trying to verify JWT token inside socket.io middleware, and put the JWT payload inside the socket to I'd access it later on the communication but I can't access the payload.

That's how I'm trying to place the JWT payload inside the socket:

```js
var server = require('http').Server(app); // intantiating the server
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.use(async (socket, next) => {
    try {
        const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
        const payload = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        socket.user_id = payload.user_id;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

After that here I can access the user_id

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("Connected: " + socket.user_id); // works
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Disconnected: " + socket.user_id); // works
    });
});
```

But here I can't access the user_id:

```js
io.of('/chatroom').on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('join', function() {
        console.log(socket.user_id) // null
    })
})
```

How can I get the value of the user_id inside the join event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding middleware to the /chatroom path like that:

```js
io.use(async (socket, next) => {
    try {
        const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
        const payload = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        socket.user_id = payload.user_id;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
io.of('/chatroom').use(async (socket, next) => {
    try {
        const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
        const payload = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        socket.user_id = payload.user_id;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, using a 3rd party libraries' internal components to store your own data is a bad practice. You should basically store this data in some place, and map between your [socketId] (which is actually the socket.io way of identifying the users connected to the server via sockets) to the [userId] (which is your way of identifying your users).

Now, there are many implementations, depends on your scalability, resources, maintenance, etc. I will suggest here some and you can read about and implement.

1. A simple Singleton class in which you will store some kind of one or more data structures (could be a hashmap), and there you will map between a [socketId] and a [userId]. Notice that only the running process will be able to get it on runtime.
2. This is a more time and resource consuming solution, but is more scalable. You can use some kind of an in-memory database, such as Redis to store this data.
   Notice that if you scale your application, all the instances can get the data from Redis since it can accept connections from all of your processes.

I am sure there are more solutions, but my advice would be to start implementing one of those and see whether you need any other implementations.